# Class abstraction and generics

Tags: java, generics

I need to extend an abstract class which I can not modify:

```
public abstract class CustomField<T> extends AbstractField<T> implements HasComponents {
    // some code

    @Override
    public abstract Class<? extends T> getType();

    // some code
}
```

With a generic class like this:

```
public class VerticalCheckBoxSelect<T> extends CustomField<Set<T>> {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Set<T>> getType() {
        return ???;
    }

}
```

My question is obvious: what should be returned by `VerticalCheckBoxSelect::getType` to be compilable (and correct)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am afraid that `return ???;` is not compilable

Comment: The `Class` type, though generic, doesn't really work with nested generics. You'll need an unchecked cast. Ex. `return (Class<? extends Set<T>>) HashSet.class;`

Comment: Thanks to Type Erasure, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @NickJ That was my concern

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis our build system fails on such unchecked cast. I will probably need to use completely different approach

Comment: Maybe this is a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you have access to an instance of the Set which type must be returned by getType, you could use `return (Class<? extends Set<T>>) theSetInstance.getClass()`.

Comment: We can tell you what would be _compilable_, but to tell you what would be _correct_ we'd need more information. What is the method actually supposed to return, what are the constraints, what is the _contract_ generally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `return Class.class.cast(HashSet.class);`

Which will compile, but will give you an unchecked assignment warning.

Comment: Finally I used `return Class.class.cast(Set.class);` but your solution is the cleanest one I would say.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

What you are actually doing is somehow equivalent to this,

```
public class VerticalCheckBoxSelect<T> extends CustomField<Set> {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Set> getType() {
        return ???;
    }
}
```

Note that on the first line it says `extends CustomField<Set>` which means that `public abstract Class<? extends T> getType()` should be implemented in a way that it will always return `Class<Set>`, so your implementation should be:

```
public class VerticalCheckBoxSelect<T> extends CustomField<Set<T>> {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Set<T>> getType() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<Set<T>> r = (Class) Set.class;
        return r;
    }
}
```

The above code is now perfectly compilable. Try it!

Now, let's say that you want it to be of arbitrary subclass of `Set` like `HashSet`, then replace the above `Set.class` with `HashSet.class`:

```
public class VerticalCheckBoxSelect<T> extends CustomField<Set<T>> {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Set<T>> getType() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<Set<T>> r = (Class) HashSet.class;
        return r;
    }
}
```